# Space in RSS feed causing joomla RSS to not compile correctly

Tags: xml, joomla, rss

Running into an issue where Joomla is compiling this RSS feed with a space at the very begginning of the file causing the RSS feed layout to break.

In the following screenshot I have the space highlighted, does anyone know where to start looking for this in Joomla?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `libraries/joomla/document/renderer/feed/rss.php` . All Joomla core feeds are ultimately generated there.